# Writing mixed data rows in a csv file

Tags: python, file, csv

I want to write rows in a .csv file along with headers where each row has both numeric value and strings. Following are the headers:

[image: CSV_Headers]

Here only the "filename" and "class" are of string type. The rest of the columns are numerical. Header should be written only once and the rows to be appended one by one. There should be no blank newline in between rows.

So I did the following:

- Initially I wrote the headers separately:

  ```
  fields = ["filename", "width", "height", "class", "xmin", "ymin", "xmax", "ymax"]

  with open(csv_file_dir, 'w') as csvfile:  
      # creating a csv writer object  
      csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile)  
      # writing the fields  
      csvwriter.writerow(fields)
  csvfile.close()
  ```
- Therefore inside a loop (where I am producing each of the data-rows) I used the similar code to append each of the rows like this (I used type-casting to convert the integers to string otherwise it was producing error like: "...iterable expected, not int"):

  ```
  rows = [str(img_SN), str(w), str(h), "eye", str(relt[0]), str(relt[1]), str(rerb[0]), str(rerb[1])] # data row
  # writing to csv file  
  with open(csv_file_dir, 'a') as csvfile:  
      # creating a csv writer object  
      csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter = ',')  
      # writing the data rows  
      csvwriter.writerows(rows)
  csvfile.close()
  ```

But it is giving totally undesired output. For example, for a sample data-row the output is as follow:

['0.jpg', '464', '350', 'eye', '107', '119', '133', '145']

Which is being written in the file as follow:

[image: Problematic output]

i.e, each of the characters is being spited and moreover it is going to newline automatically.

But the desired output be like:

Considering two sample rows:

['0.jpg', '464', '350', 'eye', '107', '119', '133', '145']

['1.jpg', '768', '576', 'eye', '131', '176', '257', '302']

The output I need like this:

[image: Desired output]

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `writerow` instead of `writerows` if you want to write only one row at a time.

Comment: Yes that worked! Thanks. Also used open(csv_file_dir, 'a',  newline = '') to prevent putting auto newline.